# Postgres Command line - clear/delete a query that I was in the middle of typing

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, postgresql-10

Is there a way to quickly delete an entire query that I've been typing?

To clarify, this would be a query I'm still typing, not something that's currently running.

For example in bash, you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it kills your current line, like:

```
$ typing some comman<CTRL-C>
```

After pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it stops the previous stuff I have typed without executing.

It's just a thing I'm used to doing for quickly switching trains of thought ("oh what if I do this instead of this?"), but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the postgres terminal just terminates the process.

Comment: If you are talking about `psql`, that's the way it is already working.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you... it wasn't working that way for me but now that you mention that it's the correct way, I realized I was running it through `su`, i.e. my command was `su - postgres -c "psql"`. Apparently, when you hit `CTRL+C` in there it always gives `Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.` regardless of whether you have another process open. I suppose if I want `CTRL+C` I'll have to manually log in as the `postgres` user first, then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aa alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> deletes all characters after the cursor.

This can be used in `bash` or many other UNIX commands, too.

Comment: @rococo `Ctrl + u` - erase the current line in terminal.